# I want to get the URL data in response with post method in postman nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, postman

I want to get data from URL in response. For example if any user gives the URL node JS code reads data and should give the output in response

below is the code I am trying with node JS but its not working

```
  if(req.body.url){
    fetch(req.body.url, res)
    .then(response => res.json())
    .then(json => res.send())
  }
```

and in the postman body I am giving like below screenshot

[image]

it is not accepting YAML data. could any help me to get that

Comment: which backend node.js framework are you using? (express.js ?)

Comment: make sure you are using some parser to parse the json. Like `app.use(express.json())`

Comment: Yes i am using express and also i am using json parser
but it won't work

Comment: Check if you're getting any errors returned with your request directly in your node.js request. Also, check if your use of `res` and `response` (two different responses) are being used correctly.